# Where to start learning about basics about sending rtp packets for audio video

Tags: webrtc, sip, rtp, rtcp

Can someone provide training or documentation about how actually video flows between two sip clients. I know basics of where client apis but don’t have much knowledge on how rtp packets are formatted , send over wire and received by other client

What are the header and what happens during packet loss
And how does a video gets converted into a rtp packet

Answer (score 0):

[Colin Perkins book](https://csperkins.org/standards/rtp-book.html) "RTP: Audio and Video for the Internet" book is, despite being published in 2003, still the best guide for this.